# Short story where a girl turns into werewolf when she has her period

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to remember the title and author of a short story I read in the 1980's in *Asimov's* about a teenage girl who turned into a werewolf when she got her period.

Comment: Can you have a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and edit in anything else you may remember? At the moment this is waaay to brief.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is likely Sarah McKee Charnas's 1989 short-story "[Boobs](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41590)".

First publication was in Asimov's.

The story is [available for free on-line](https://talesofmytery.blogspot.com/2013/10/suzy-mckee-charnas-boobs.html), so it's easy to check, but the plot revolves around the emotional life of a young lady returning to school with visible secondary sexual characteristics, getting teased about it, discovering that she turns into a werewolf during that time of month, and finding self-worth and freedom therein. Oh, and a little revenge.

The story was nominated for the Nebula and won the Hugo and other awards.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have to ask: are you related? I went to college with an Andy Charnas, who initially turned me on to her writing.

Comment: No relation that I'm aware of. There are few enough McKees that meeting another is notable, but enough that the relationship is usually fairly tenuous.